# "Invalid character value for cast specification" when using pyodbc in Python

Tags: python, pyodbc

I have made a python script that connects to Mssql database and inserts something there.

Problem is in this line:

```
cursor.execute("insert into TREND_DATA (TREND_ID, TREND_DATE, TREND_VALUE) values ((select TREND_ID from TRENDS where TREND_NAME = ?), ?, ?)", name, date, trend_value)
```

After this line I get this error:

```
cursor.execute("insert into TREND_DATA (TREND_ID, TREND_DATE, TREND_VALUE) values ((select TREND_ID from TRENDS where TREND_NAME = ?), ?, ?)", name, date, trend_value)
pyodbc.DataError: ('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid character value for cast specification (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

I tried putting 'abc' instead of "name" but i get the same error"

```
cursor.execute("insert into TREND_DATA (TREND_ID, TREND_DATE, TREND_VALUE) values ((select TREND_ID from TRENDS where TREND_NAME = ?), ?, ?)", 'abc', date, trend_value)
```

However  this line works and I get new lines in database:

```
cursor.execute("insert into TREND_DATA (TREND_ID, TREND_DATE, TREND_VALUE) values ((select TREND_ID from TRENDS where TREND_NAME = 'abc'), ?, ?)", date, trend_value)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I was able to reproduce your issue with pyodbc 4.0.22 under Python2. I just tried your original `.execute` under pyodbc 4.0.23 (released today) and it worked fine for me. Try upgrading to the latest version and see if that helps.

Comment: @GordThompson's solution worked for me. I literally just got this exact same issue (last week) and ran into a brick wall until you asked this question. Updated pyodbc and I am not getting this error now.

Comment: @MichaelPlautz - Thanks for the confirmation. I have posted my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changes introduced in pyodbc 4.0.22 caused several different errors while working with query parameters. Those issues were addressed by the release of pyodbc 4.0.23.

Comment: @KonradSitarz - If you have a specific issue with the current version of pyodbc then consider posting the relevant details [as a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) or [as an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues).

Answer (score 1):

I was having this error and was able to solve this by matching the types from the source with the destination.

In my case, I was bulk converting all the source to string before the insert and at the destination table actually had a 2 float columns.

After matching the types, the insert worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use format to solve this:

```
cursor.execute("insert into TREND_DATA (TREND_ID, TREND_DATE, TREND_VALUE) values ((select TREND_ID from TRENDS where TREND_NAME = {0}), ?, ?)".format(name), date, trend_value)
```

It seems like the ? inside () is a problem.

However this has some security implications and should not be used as permanent solution.

Comment: This entirely defeats the purpose of parameterization. Any time you use strings to build an SQL query in code, you have to thoroughly vet your input to prevent SQL injection attacks. What if `name` were set to `'' OR 1=1`? The intent of the query has been compromised. Parameterization takes care of all of these security measures for you. This is a debug measure at best. I had this issue and was able to resolve it with @GordTompson's suggestion.

Comment: @MichaelPlautz alright thanks for the info. I added a warning to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

Used **bulk_save_objects** and worked pretty well, but with pyodbc 4.0.22 it began to throw a type cast error for bigints (long in python).

```
'[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification (0) (SQLExecDirectW)') [SQL: u'INSERT INTO [gg_expo] ([ID], [Status], [Timestamp]) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: ((3903146347805142551L, 1, u'2018-08-01T09:06:34.244'), (3959371193446428183L, 0, u'2018-08-01T09:06:55.128'),
```

I had to use **add_all(the_list_of_rows)**. Hope this helps someone!